# Comparing 2 word Documents in Office 2003

Tags: ms-word

we have word Document(office 2003) Containing Bookmarks(Template) - We Generate the Document Via Application under Test(Final Document)(Office 2003)- Based on the data we enter in the Application under Test -Book mark gets filled and Document Gets Printed

So now I need to Compare the template with the Final Document 
What is the Best Approach to compare the 2 documents

Note: I need to Compare the Margin , font and all other formatting stuffs as well

Initial Analaysis - I Converted the 2003 template and the final document to 2010 word format and changed the File type to .zip - when we extract it i got numerous XML - I compared both the XML - but that is not adding value for this kind of test why because eventhough there is a discrepancy it is becoming really difficult to Map the contents in XML to the actual contents in the word document

Answer (score 0):

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) has a [plugin](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiffPlugin/en/index.html) that handles Word 2003/2007 files.